# No module named 'RECC'

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried to :
`import REC from RECC`

This error message comes up:

> No module named 'RECC'

I don't understand what i have to do.Can I not install RECC in Windows ? can someone help me ? thanks

Comment: Have you tried `pip install recc`?

Comment: Also, I get a syntax error from that line, shouldn't it be `from RECC import REC`?

Comment: yes I have tried. But I got this error message: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     raise RuntimeError('uvloop does not support Windows at the moment')
    RuntimeError: uvloop does not support Windows at the moment.                     PS: I have windows 11

Comment: Which Python distribution are you using? If not Conda, you might have more luck installing Miniconda3 or Anaconda3 and working in that environment. A Google search tells me it supports Windows 11.

Comment: I use Python 3.9.12.

Comment: But how did you install Python 3.9.12? Via Conda, or via some other installer? If you used the regular Python for Windows installer, I recommend trying Miniconda3 instead, it generally makes installing many packages much easier.

Comment: yeah exactly, via Conda. do you also use Windows ? I think this package does not work in Windows.

Comment: Just tested `pip install recc` in my Conda environment on Windows 10, and you're right, it's not supported. But the problem is not recc itself, it's the uvloop package it depends on. `pip install recc` gives me this informative error message: `RuntimeError: uvloop does not support Windows at the moment`.

Comment: i got the same problem as you. i installed subsystem on my computer and tried with linux. I got this error message: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement recc (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for recc    i don t know what should i do

Comment: I know this is not an answer, but do you really need this module? Can you do your work with something else? (Full disclosure, I've never used recc, I've just been trying to reproduce your problem to try to help.)

Comment: yes i need it, i need to build a recursive algorithm on a gauss process. I looked on the internet and this was the only package I found.